# Display size comparison chart?

Tags: laptop, resolution, display

I am in the process of collecting laptop recommendations for a friend. I need a way to show to her the size differences of the various formats (15" 4:3, 15" 16:9, 15" 16:10 .... up to 17.3") in a graphical way, so she can compare them to the laptop she currently has (15").

Does anybody know a simple comparison chart where those sizes are shown side-by-side?

We have E-Mail connection only right now, so I would need some sort of a link or PDF document.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [DisplayWars.com](http://displaywars.com/) It will allow you to visually see the difference between screens of different sizes and aspect ratios. Only downside is that you can only compare two at a time. Here's an example (difference between a 4:3 13" display and a 16:9 15" display):

[image]

Comment: Cheers @Alex, I will be able to put something together with this.

Comment: @Pekka glad to know it helped!

Answer (score 2):

Not side-by-side, but instead overlaid, but very comprehensive:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_size

  "Diagram comparing various typical screen sizes by width, height, diagonal, area and aspect ratio [color-coded]." -- Includes A4 (8" x 11"), A3 (11" x 17") paper designators for comparison.
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution

  "This chart shows the most common display resolutions, with the color of each resolution type indicating the display ratio..." -- Includes designators like CGA, WUXGA, HD1080.